# Control in UpdatePanel loses value

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have two comboboxes, first one triggers updatepanel that updates second one:

```
        protected void cb1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        cb2.DataSource = DT1;
        cb2.DataBind();


         }
```

Problem is, when I click button, all values are ok, except one in UpdatePanel, so updatepanel somehow resets selected index on child controls.

Any idea how to fix this?

I know about sessions, but I don't know on what step to assign value of cb2 to session.

Thanks.

Update, aspx

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="False" 
                                                        UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="cb2" runat="server" Height="22px" ValueField="ID" 
                                                                ValueType="System.Int32" Width="170px">
                                                                <Columns>
                                                                    <dx:ListBoxColumn Caption="ID" FieldName="ID" Visible="False" />
                                                                    <dx:ListBoxColumn Caption="City" FieldName="City" />
                                                                </Columns>
                                                            </dx:ASPxComboBox>
</ContentTemplate>
                                                    <Triggers>
                                                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger
    ControlID="cb1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                                                        </Triggers>
                                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Can you post some of the code from your aspx? The sample I've setup based on your given scenario worked fine - cb2 had the selected value on postback.

Comment: @GuthMD here is aspx. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things here: you have `ChildrenAsTriggers="False"`, but yet you have an async postback trigeer for a child control: 'cb2'. I think you should *remove* the `ChildrenAsTriggers="False"` property ("true" is default value) and you probably meant to have the ansync postback trigeer set to the `cb1' control like below:

```
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
    <ContentTemplate>
      <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="cb2" runat="server" Height="22px" ValueField="ID"     
                       ValueType="System.Int32" Width="170px">  
        <Columns>
           <dx:ListBoxColumn Caption="ID" FieldName="ID" Visible="False" /> 
           <dx:ListBoxColumn Caption="City" FieldName="City" /> 
        </Columns>                                                             
    </dx:ASPxComboBox> 
   </ContentTemplate>                                                     
   <Triggers>                                                         
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="cb1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />   
   </Triggers>                                                     
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Also I think your original code copied was missing the opening `<ContentTemplate>` tag.

At this point your cb1 control's event `cb1_SelectedIndexChanged' should fire and be able to update the cb2 control's datasource in the UpdatePanel above.

Comment: You're right, cb1 is trigger, I missed that and content template, when I tried to format code here on S.O.
I also tried with ChildrenAsTriggers="True", but allways, selected index is -1 (which is for not selected). 
cb1 indeed fires update panel and successfully binds cb2 (i see that I have 10 items when I set break point) but selected index is still problem.

Comment: I am not sure about your 3rd party dx:ASPxComboBox, but upon binding natuarally the 1st item in the list is the one displayed. Are you saying the cb1 control is loosing its selected value? If yes, make sure that update panel has `UpdateMode="Conditional"` and do not set `ChildrenAsTriggers="false"`. My guess is the value is changed in code, or rebound to a datasource -> this will **absolutely** cause the value to not be retained and go back to -1, or the UpdatePanel for the containing control is improperly configured.

Comment: On same form I have several others aspxcombobox-es, that are outside panel, and they all works just fine, and all are configured like cb2. cb1 is not loosing selected value, but cb2 (inside panel - does). It shouldn't be rebound, as its binded just on cb1 sel. ind. changed event, not on button click.
What do you mean by "changed in code"? Thanks.

Comment: When does cb2 loose its selected value? There is *no* value selected upon being bound (unless you are programatically setting it) so I am not sure *when* cb2 looses its selected value exactly? Upons being bound its value *should* be the default value in the list.

Comment: It was never selected, in other words, never changed from default value. I just founded that I, before binding, set selected index to null (I wanted cb2 blank every time I change cb1), and obviously when I set that to null, for some reason, it cant be selected later to something else. Thank you @actonway for leading me on right way :) and thanks all others who took time to help.